# Contents of the page in firefox after restarting

Tags: firefox

In my firefox open some tabs. After restarting, tabs re-loaded from the network. How to make their content is loaded from the cache, as in the Opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Look for the Work Offline in the File menu.**
>   If you have the orange Firefox menu button then you can use Firefox > Web Developer > Work Offline
>
> You can find the location of the disk cache on the about:cache page.
>
> In case you are using "Clear history when Firefox closes":
>
> ```
> do not clear the Cache because Firefox will disable the disk cache in such a case 
>
> Tools > Options > Privacy > Firefox will: "Use custom settings for history": [X] "Clear history when Firefox closes" > Settings
> https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Clear+Recent+History
> ```
>
> Note that clearing "Site Preferences" clears all exceptions for
>   cookies, images, pop-up windows, software installation, and passwords.
>
> The offline (application) cache is used by other applications to store
>   data and serves a different purpose.
>
> ```
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache
> ```
>
> Modified June 15, 2013 2:35:29 PM PDT by cor-e

- via [enter link description here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962145)

note this is assuming you are in FF21 or newer
l